# Why does PlaybackState remain at Playing after PlaybackStopped fires?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I'm a little new to using NAudio so I'm surely missing something important, hence this question.

Starting with example/demo code, I put together a class as simple as I could make it to play MP3 or WAV files:

```
public class AudioPlayer : IDisposable
{
    WaveStream _waveStream; // sound data stream
    WaveChannel32 _waveChannel32; // sound channel ??
    IWavePlayer _iWavePlayer; // sound output driver

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return _iWavePlayer != null 
                     && _iWavePlayer.PlaybackState 
                         != Wave.PlaybackState.Stopped; }
    }

    public PlaybackState PlaybackState
    {
        get { return _iWavePlayer.PlaybackState; }
    }

    public void LoadMp3(byte[] mp3Bytes)
    {
        Load(CreateInputStreamFromMp3Bytes(mp3Bytes));
    }

    public void LoadFile(string filename)
    {
        Load(CreateInputStream(filename));
    }

    void Load(WaveStream waveStream)
    {
        if (_iWavePlayer != null)
            Dispose();
        _iWavePlayer = new WaveOut();
        _iWavePlayer.PlaybackStopped += 
            new EventHandler(_iWavePlayer_PlaybackStopped);
        _waveStream = waveStream;
        _waveChannel32 = new WaveChannel32(_waveStream);
        _waveChannel32.PadWithZeroes = false;
        _iWavePlayer.Init(_waveChannel32);
    }

    void _iWavePlayer_PlaybackStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }

    static WaveStream CreateInputStreamFromMp3Bytes(byte[] mp3Bytes)
    {
        return new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(mp3Bytes), false);
    }

    static WaveStream CreateInputStream(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
            return new WaveFileReader(fileName);
        else if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
            return new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        _iWavePlayer.Play();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_iWavePlayer != null 
                && _iWavePlayer.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped) { 
            _iWavePlayer.Stop();
            _waveStream.Position = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stop();
        if (_iWavePlayer != null) {
            _iWavePlayer.Dispose();
            _iWavePlayer = null;
        }
        if (_waveChannel32 != null) {
            _waveChannel32.Dispose();
            _waveChannel32 = null;
        }
        if (_waveStream != null) {
            _waveStream.Dispose();
            _waveStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the code in question to play MP3 files (not WAVs).

It works ok for the most part, which is pretty awesome considering that I'll be able to replace MediaElements in my project. The issue I'm having is that the `PlaybackState` stays at `Playing` rather than changing to `Stopped` once PlaybackStopped fires. To go around that, I subscribe to `PlaybackStopped` and call `Stop()` from there.

Is it normal that I have to call `Stop()` like that, or is there is something I am missing here?

Comment: Not a class I'm familiar with, but many objects raise the "Stopped" event while still playing, in case you want to cancel, it makes the state changes simpler.  Is the event cancelable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug. If you look at NAudio code `WaveOut` will not change `PlaybackState` in `RaisePlaybackStoppedEvent`. But `DirectSoundOut` will change it to stopped. A little crazy.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks with DirectSoundOut? Do you happen to have some code that plays MP3s with it that you could share :-) ?

Comment: Nevermind the sample, I just replaced WaveOut with DirectSoundOut and it indeeds sets the state to stopped when finished.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In the Load method change this line:

```
_iWavePlayer = new WaveOut();
```

by this:

```
_iWavePlayer = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
```